# What happens if you don't answer the phone after watching the Ring tape?

Tags: the-ring

We know that when someone watches the film they get a call that says

> "You have 7 days"

**What if the person doesn't answer the call?** Is the person going to die anyway ?

Comment: This [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/46h6eo/the_ring_what_happens_if_you_dont_answer_the_phone/) suggests that Noah didn't pick up the phone but still died after watching the video.

Comment: *"If the viewer does not answer Samara's phone call, she will leave a message on an answer machine as seen when Noah Clay watches the tape."*

Comment: No need to overly complicate things: you die in 7 days after watching the film because it took seven days for Samara to die in the well. The ring is literally her view looking up from the well and seeing the ring of sunlight cast around the circle shaped stone used to seal up the well. Whether viewer even understands this is immaterial. 7 days from watching, dead.

Comment: Interesting question to compare to *Ringu*: would you still die if there were no TV or screen nearby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes they would**

According the [TV Tropes page on *The Ring*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Headscratchers/TheRing), where this is addressed:

> Noah watched the tape but did not answer the phone when it rang for him. He heard the phone ring and asked Rachel if she was going to get it. He still died.

Comment: He got the message another way though, from the bellhop.

Comment: @Valorum so maybe the rule is "the message will arrive another way, and you'll still die".