# In "The Ring", what if you just went somewhere with no electronics?

Tags: the-ring

I mean if you watched the cursed video and went somewhere with absolutely no electricity, could you still get murderfied?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if you don't answer the phone after watching the Ring tape?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152611) I think the accepted answer in the linked q explains that, even though it's a slightly different situation, the person still died.

Comment: @Gail - Do you have a particular continuity in mind? Original Japanese? American? The rules _might_ be a little different. The rules did vary slightly between the original version of _The Grudge_ and the remake with western actors.